# Firefox extremely slow at clearing tables

Tags: performance, firefox, html-table, rendering

I'm testing my code that works with dynamic tables in Firefox. The tables I play with are ~1000 rows long and get generated from search results that are in JSON via templating engine.

The resulting string is like `<table><thead>...` and then I place the table into a placeholder element like this: `$('#holder').html(str)`.

The first search gets rendered fast, where as the following ones are extremely slow. And it seems that most of the time takes placeholder clearing.

That is, if I place `$('#holder').html("")` or `$('#holder').empty()` before placing a new table, then this clearing takes much time and the rendering of the new table itself is as fast as it was.

Speaking about the numbers, rendering takes only 90 milliseconds whereas clearing takes 16 seconds.

I wrote this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cJGR3/2/

If you press "Test me" consequently, you will notice that clearing will take most of the time.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this Firefox 4? I've just run that fiddle in 4.0.1 and everything seems to be working just fine?

Comment: also in 3.6.17 clearing is about 76 ms. do you have firebug open?

Comment: Firebug was the reason of the that extreme slowness (16 seconds).

Comment: Sounds like you should report a bug to Firebug about their content removed handlers being super-slow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by **DanielB**, Firebug was the reason.